# how to get the row key from hbase scan result

Tags: java, hbase

when scan the hbase table row by row, how can i get the row key? here is my code:

```
for (Result rr : scanner) {
   System.out.println(rr);
}
```

is there any method like getKey() that i can use? thanks.

Answer (score 37):

If you want the row key in a string format, use the `getRow` and the `Bytes.toString` methods :

```
for (Result rr : scanner) {
   String key = Bytes.toString(rr.getRow())
}
```

[HBase API - Result object](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html)

`getRow()` Method for retrieving the row key that corresponds to the row from which this Result was created.

Comment: I saw getRow() in the method list and that was the only candidate to retrieve the RowKey. Just curious, why they decided to name it getRow() and not getRowKey()?

Comment: Is this answer correct? I wonder why it is not accepted if so.

Comment: @Mahdi this answer is correct. According to the docs "Method for retrieving the row key that corresponds to the row from which this Result was created."(https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getRow--).

Comment: I am getting incorrect row, does it returns encoded string?